# ReSharper code style issue, parentheses line break

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (version 14.0.25431.1) with JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2017.2.2  (built on 2017 October 06)

I have this code (with my current configurations):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name : "Default",
    url : "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults : new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

And I want to look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name     : "Default",
    url      : "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults : new {
        controller = "Home",
        action     = "Index",
        id         = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Anyone knows how to do this?
Any improvement will be really appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the visual studio's Pre-defined Keyboard Shortcuts to format you code. 
To format a document **Ctrl + E + D** or **Ctrl + K + D** 
To format a selection **Ctrl + K + F**

See [visual studio's Pre-defined Keyboard Shortcuts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: The OP was asking how to format their code in a particular way, not what keyboard shortcuts to use to format their code.

Comment: @PiersMyers Exactly

Answer (score 0):

Neither Visual Studio or Resharper will do this kind of formatting. Try the [Code alignment extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpmcgrath.Codealignment).

Be aware that if you do this type of formatting it will add some maintenance overhead for others who may work on your code. Also Visual Studio or Resharper may undo all your careful alignments at some point.

Comment: What do you mean with "maintenance overhead" and why this will produce that?. Thanks for your response and info!